GCP PubSub Authorisation Issue In Java Using Service Account
I am facing below issue while publishing messages to various topics from one java service.

exception is com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized
to perform this
action.\ncom.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubDeliveryException:
Publishing to
projects/testing-development/topics/testing-bacd-testing-1 topic
failed.; nested exception is
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized
to perform this action.\n\tat
com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.publisher.PubSubPublisherTemplate$1.onFailure(PubSubPublisherTemplate.java:111)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:95)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:77)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.SettableApiFuture.setException(SettableApiFuture.java:52)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$OutstandingBatch.onFailure(Publisher.java:545)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$OutstandingBatch.access$1600(Publisher.java:512)\n\tat
com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$3.onFailure(Publisher.java:488)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.handleAttempt(BasicRetryingFuture.java:200)\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.retrying.CallbackChainRetryingFuture$AttemptCompletionListener.handle(CallbackChainRetryingFuture.java:135)\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.retrying.CallbackChainRetryingFuture$AttemptCompletionListener.run(CallbackChainRetryingFuture.java:117)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:95)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.setException(AbstractApiFuture.java:77)\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)\n\tat
com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)\n\tat
com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)\n\tat
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)\n\tat
io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:463)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:427)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:460)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:553)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:68)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:739)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:718)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)\n\tat
io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)\n\tat
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\n\tat
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\nCaused by:
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized
to perform this action.\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55)\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)\n\tat
com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)\n\t...
24 common frames omitted\nCaused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.\n\tat
io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)\n\t... 16 common
frames omitted\n","context":"default"}

My Setup
We are trying to publish to many topics from one java service.
We have created

topics1 => using a wrapper library over spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub and using it to publish to some of the topics
topics2 => using spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub directly to publish to other topics and this is behind a conditional property.

We are seeing above error for all the topics in topics1 when conditional property for topics2 is enabled.
Attempts

There was library version mismatch, fixed it.
Tried to run it locally with minimal setup and it is working fine.
Checked permissions of service account being used and it has all the required permissions.
Enabled pubsub auditing as well to find out but pubsub doesn't log Publish API calls.

I would like to find out what is this user who is not authorised. Is there some access_token invalidation happening ?
Thanks in advance.

The issue was google cloud platform credentials initialisation. we use service account and use its key in pods.
So both the libraries were trying to initialise gcp credentials initialisation but one was having null credentials.
We found out this by attaching remote debugger to a pod running in kubernetes.
Although we still don't know why creds initialisation was not happening properly but we found a quick workaround to fix the problem by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and then another library located creds fine.
